# How to pass a UI response to a variable in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I am an absolute beginner and using some code from the documentation, I am trying to pass a user interface response to a variable and then place it on a sheet.
The response gets into the logger OK but only "Response from user" appears in the cell.
The piece of code is:

```
    if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
          Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
           var name=response; 
           var target1 = tr.getRange(8, 25).activate();   // a test cell in sheet
              target1.setValue(name); 
                } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
```

Comment: You're defining the response object itself as `name`, not the text inside of the object.

Comment: var name=response; should be replaced by var name=response.getResponseText();

As you got only 2 option, you should have If & else and not if and else if

Comment: Hey @SupportBase, were you able to solve your issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
function gettingAResponse() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Are you ten feet tall?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You pressed yes');
    sh.getRange("E5:E6").setValues([["Your response is:"],[resp.getResponseText()]]);
  }
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.NO) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You pressed no.");
    sh.getRange("E5:E6").setValues([["Your response is:"],[resp.getResponseText()]]);
  }
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You pressed cancel");
    sh.getRange('E5:E6').clearContent();
  }
}
```

[Another Example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are doing the following:

```js
var name=response; 
var target1 = tr.getRange(8, 25).activate();   // a test cell in sheet
target1.setValue(name);
```

However, if what you want, is to set the actual response value in your cell, you have to do it as follows (notice the difference in the first line):

```js
var name=response.getResponseText(); 
var target1 = tr.getRange(8, 25).activate();   // a test cell in sheet
target1.setValue(name);
```

Further to that, I suggest that you evaluate whether you need the [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate()) function call, and that you check out the [troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) page in the documentation (it can save you lots of time!).

#### Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getResponseText()